# Setting favicon in FastAPI over https

Tags: python, api, https, fastapi, favicon

I have deployed an API on a Ubuntu server and set-up Nginx and SSL so that all requests are made through https.

In FastAPI, I have set a favicon route to set the favicon for the site and this works during development, however in production I get the following error message in the browser console:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://thefootballdata.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://thefootballdata.com/favicon.ico/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

[image]

This is the code that I am using as a route for the favicon:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse


router = APIRouter(prefix="/favicon.ico")

favicon_path = "./static/images/favicon/ball.ico"


@router.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
def favicon():
    return FileResponse(favicon_path)
```

Comment: ```favicon_path = "https://thefootballdata.com/static/images/favicon/ball.ico"```

Comment: What is the favicon reference in your generated HTML/application?

Comment: @tomerar Still the same issue

Comment: @MatsLindh No favicon reference is generated

Comment: Oh, you've included `"/"` in your `@router.get` method - this means that FastAPI will issue a http redirect to '/favicon.ico/` - try `@router.get("", ..)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the `/` and the end of a route path, FastAPI adds a redirect if the same path is requested without the ending slash (so `/users` gets redirected to `/users/` if you've registered `/users/`).

In this case you've added `@router.get("/")` which means a path ending with  `/` under the base path you've given when creating APIRouter. Since this issues a redirect, and FastAPI doesn't have information about the request being a `https` request (probably missing headers, hard to say), the redirect is issued with an `http` address instead.

Removing `/` from the route solves the issue:

```py
@router.get("", include_in_schema=False)
def favicon():
    return FileResponse(favicon_path)
```